# Проектирование БД: все таблицы "многие ко многим"?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, таблицы, многие-ко-многим

Впервые пытаюсь спроектировать базу данных, не имея даже отдаленно целостного представления о предмете. Поэтому прошу не ругаться на мою безграмотность, не программист я.

В БД предполагается три таблицы: КЛИЕНТЫ, КВАРТИРЫ, АГЕНТЫ 
При этом:

1. каждый клиент может выбрать много квартир, но работать с ним будет один агент;
2. каждую квартиру будут просматривать много клиентов и агентов;
3. каждый агент может работать со многими квартирами и многими клиентами.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что у меня нет родительской таблицы при таких условиях? Такая ситуация возможна?

Спасибо!

Comment: Безусловно возможна. Я вижу здесь одну `mtm`таблицу - `АГЕНТЫ_КВАРТИРЫ` и связь один_ко_многим `АГЕНТ_КЛИЕНТЫ`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ